# JQuery drag/drop swap

Tags: jquery-ui

I borrowed the following code from another post and it works for as far as it goes.  I need to swap between two lists of items.  I can't figure out how to change the code for multiple items.

I'm using Coldfusion so where you see cfoutput I am looping over a query.  I do it twice.  Once for starting lineup players (they have a valid week number) and again for bench players.  The idea is to move a bench player to the starting lineup.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#wrapper {
   border: thin dotted orange;   
}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery.fn.swapWith = function(to) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var copy_to = $(to).clone();
                var copy_from = $(this).clone();
                $(to).replaceWith(copy_from);
                $(this).replaceWith(copy_to);
            });
        };



        $(document).ready(function() {

            options = {
                    revert: true,
                    helper: 'clone'
            };

            $("li").draggable(options);
            $('#wrapper').droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui) {
        //      window.setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#one').swapWith($('#two'));
                    $(".ui-draggable-dragging").remove();
                    $("li").draggable(options);
        //}, 1);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <ul id="wrapper">
        <li id='one'>
            <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid green">
                one<br /></div>
        </li>
        <li id='two'>
            <div style="width: 110px; height: 110px; border: 1px solid red">
                two<br /></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give some more detail and what is and isn't working? And/or post the generated html source so maybe we can run it to see what's going on.

Comment: The code is at http://jsfiddle.net/58WWX/10/

Comment: What the heck happened to this thread?  I've lost several comments.